# Retrieve data from a drop down that is created dynamically with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to load data from a database into a drop down menu, and then take the results of that drop down menu, and use them to again interact with the database.

My code to load in the drop down works fine:

```
    var optionsValues = '<select name="catMenu id="catMenu>';
    var lcDest, lcInfo;

    lcDest = "adminIncludes/loadCats.php"; 

    $.getJSON(lcDest, function(data) {
        lcInfo = data.items;
        $.each(lcInfo, function(index, info) {
            optionsValues += '<option value="' + info.S_ID + '">' + info.S_Name + '</option>';
        });
        optionsValues += '</select>';
        $("#catTable").html(optionsValues);
    });
```

My issue now is how to interact with the user input from this drop down box?

I have tried using the usual methods:

```
('#catMenu').val();
document.getElementById("catMenu");
```

But they don't seem to work, I'm assuming this is because the 'catMenu' drop down box was created after the HTML loaded in.

What method should I use to interact with the drop down box?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you close out your attributes properly; try changing the first line to: `var optionsValues = '<select name="catMenu" id="catMenu">';`

Comment: Use [jQuery's `.on()` event](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind to the AJAX created select field. Also, did you want changing the new select field to trigger something, or do you just need to get the field's selected option upon submitting a form?

Comment: I only wanted to get the selected option when the form is submitted.  And thanks i'll read up in .on() now

Answer (score 2):

Your quotes are messed up so you have invalid HTML in your select tag.

```
var optionsValues = '<select name="catMenu id="catMenu>';
```

Should be

```
var optionsValues = '<select name="catMenu" id="catMenu">';
```

Comment: Good shout, this hasn't made it work though, not sure how i missed up those quotes though haha